# WPF C# ICollectionView enumerating through items in a group

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, icollectionview

UPDATE:
So I created a IValueConverter which I access through a PropertyGroupDescription. I have managed some helpful things with it but have not been able to fix my issue.

My current problem is accessing the object type:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
CultureInfo culture)
{
var obj = targetType as MyType // Error, can't convert to mytype
var obj = targetType as IGrouping<System.String, MyType>; // no error but returns null
...
```

Maybe I miss undastand what targettype is, but I can't do anything with it.

What I am trying to do is pass the grouped object, a IGrouping < System.String, MyType> to my converter, so I can loop through it to put the contained items into the correct groups via this line of code:

```
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(
    new PropertyGroupDescription(groupBy,
    new MyConverter()));
```

---

I would like the view to render like this on screen:

-------------- Group is true = true(2 items) --------------------

stack1 true and false (20 items)

stack3 only true (x items)

------------- Group is true = false( 2 items) ------------------

stack1 true and false (13 items)

stack2 only false (x items)

---

Currently it displays like this:

-------------- Group is true = true(2 items) --------------------

stack1 true and false (33 items)

stack3 only true (x items)

------------- Group is true = false( 1 item) ------------------

stack2 only false (x items)

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand what you're trying to do. Are you somehow trying to "flatten" this nested grouping and organize them by the inner property?

Comment: Try to create a fuller code example that includes classes that closely reflect the structure of your actual data: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to create an interface.  See following two links 1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control 2) (from 2005) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00fdff88-7a2a-47f2-9cb6-017780c535f7/grouping-properties-and-methods?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: I have updated my query. And on the topic of interfaces: If no quick and easy option is available, perhaps an implementation of the IValueConverter inside the PropertyGroupDescription? Dose that sound like a possible solution and if so, perhaps an example of how it could be applied to this situation? To clarify, everything is working, except an equivalent of FirstOrDefault is used by GroupDescriptions on items in a view, I need to iterate through more than one entry for each item as an IGrouping<System.String, MyClass>

Comment: It seems flattening is what I want.Rather than getting a list of lists I just want the information in  the lists. For some reason though, I can't use select many using the syntax shown in the question, it tells me that the command is unrecognised . If any of you guys could convert the select query above market query into a select many query, it could be problem solved.

Comment: So no one has an answer for this problem?